# Meteor: Can't subscribe data

Tags: meteor

Somehow I solved my problem.

I wasn't using **Meteor.methods**, then i started to use them.

I am still not using the subscription, publish things.

## --- Solution ---

**In server/methods.js**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        insertDoc: function(someValueToInsert1, someValueToInsert2) {
            return Docs.insert({
                owner: Meteor.user().username,
                type: someValueToInsert1,
                files: someValueToInsert2
            });

            // `return Docs.insert()` function because
            // Docs.insert returning the _id value of
            // this entry. And i will use the _id value
            // at client side.

            // For ex.: Insert doc and go to doc page
            // Used router like this:
            // http:// ... /document/:id/view
            // http:// ... /document/:id/edit
            // http:// ... /document/:id/general

        }
    });
}
```

**In client/upload.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.upload.events({
        'click #uploadButton': function(){

            // Some variable definitons
            // like someValueToInsert1, someValueToInsert2 etc

            Meteor.call('insertDoc', someValueToInsert1, someValueToInsert2);

            // That's all.
            // But you can add your callback your Meteor.call function
            // To pass data from server to client like:

            Meteor.call('insertDoc', someValueToInsert1, someValueToInsert2, function(error, result) {
                if(!error) Router.go('seeUploadedDataByID', { id: result });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

## ---My Problem was---

Tried too many ways.

My app: User can create docs. Docs is a collection.

If User creates doc, pushing the doc id into Meteor.user().profile.docs.

What i did:

**Way 1: In Router.js**

```
Router.route("/docs", {
    "name": "docs",
    data: function(){
        var userDocs = Meteor.users.find({_id: thisId}, {fields: {"profile.docs": 1}});;
        return Docs.find({_id: {$all: userDocs}});

        // console.log(Docs.find({_id: {$all: userDocs}}))
        // This console.log returns a weird data, not what i want
        // It looks like Mongo function
    }
});
```

**Way 2: In server/publishs.js**

```
Meteor.publish("myDocs", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {"profile": 1}});
    // Actually i wanted to reach userData first
    // If i can reach datas, i will try to reach profile.docs
});
```

then **in client/docs.js**

```
Template.docs.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe("myDocs");
});
```

then **in client/docs.html**

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#each myDocs}}
        {{this.docs}}
        {{this.profile}}
        {{this}}
        {{this[0]}}</div>
    {{/each}}
{{else}}
    Loading...
{{/if}}
```

When i rendered, says Loading.. then nothing appers.

**Way3: In client/docs.js**

```
Template.docs.helpers({
    myDocs: function(){
        var docs = Meteor.user().profile.docs;
        var docsArr = [];
        for (var i=0;i<docs.length;i++){
            var doc = Docs.findOne({_id: docs[i]});
            docsArr.push(doc);
        }
        return docsArr;
    }
});
```

I am trying to solve this during the time while awake.

**Q:** Should i create a new User collection and push docId's into it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the username, emails and profile are published.
So you could try this solution:

router.js

```
Router.route('/docs', {
    name: 'docs',
    waitOn: function() {
        if(Meteor.user()){
            return Meteor.subscribe('myDocs', Meteor.user().profile.docs);
        }
    }
});
```

server/publishs.js

```
Meteor.publish("myDocs", function(docs) {
    return Docs.find({_id: {$in: docs}});
});
```

client/docs.html

```
{{#each myDocs}}
    {{title}}
    {{description}}
{{/each}}
```

client/docs.js

```
Template.docs.helpers({
    myDocs: function(){
        return Docs.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually i figured it out and many thanks for your interest. I decided to use _Meteor.methods_ which is feels me more secure.